# How can I open a child case for a supply-point case in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to open child cases for supply point cases in an app, however I believe I will have to set the owner ID manually for these child cases. Is this assumption correct? Are there other specific workarounds I will have to consider when setting up child cases for a supply point case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to set the `owner_id` unless your workflow is non-standard. The basic assumption is that all cases will be opened by the facility level user. If this isn't the case e.g. supervisors are creating the child cases, then you will have to manually set the case owner.

You can read more about how to do that on the help site: https://help.commcarehq.org/display/commcarepublic/Assigning+Cases+to+One+of+Multiple+Locations